# Is the illusory copy of the caster from the Project Image spell immune to any types of damage?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, damage, illusion, damage-types

The spell [Project Image](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/project-image) states:

> The illusion looks and sounds like you but is intangible.

and also

> If the illusion takes any damage, it disappears, and the spell ends.

Does the intangibility of the illusion imply immunity to one or more damage types?

As an example, one might imagine that damage based on having a tangible physical thing to hurt, like non-magical bludgeoning damage, may not apply.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## No, it is not immune to any damage

If it had an immunity, it would say so. But it doesn't, so it doesn't.

There also is no general rule for illusion damage immunities/resistances that would apply here (or to other illusions.)